# How to move EC2 instance to another ECS cluster

Tags: amazon-ecs

Assume I have two clusters `devcluster` and `qacluster` on [ECS](https://aws.amazon.com/ecs/). 
How to remove an EC2 instance *(ecs-optimized amazon-linux)* from `qacluster`  and add to `devcluster`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to follow these steps:

- Set `ECS_CLUSTER=devcluster` in `/etc/ecs/ecs.config`
- Stop all tasks/containers
- Remove checkpoint file - `/var/lib/ecs/data/ecs_agent_data.json`
- Start ECS agent again as explained here - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/ecs-agent-install.html

To make sure it uses correct cluster, check logs - `docker logs ecs-agent`. It should have a message like:

```
[INFO] Registration completed successfully. I am running as 'arn:aws:ecs:eu-west-1:ACCOUNT_ID:container-instance/CLUSTER_ID' in cluster 'devcluster'
```

Comment: You should avoid publishing any ressource arn without masking your account id and the ressource id in my opinion. I've edited and cleared the the revision history.

Comment: @Tensibai you're totally right. But it was actually masked as I have replaced last 6 digits with zeros ;) But this change would not harm.

Comment: There's a small chance it match someone else account number, prefer replacing with xxxx than with 0 to avoid bots scanning the internet launching attacks :)

Answer (score 2):

The way a cluster becomes aware of the EC2 instances associated to it, is a configuration file used by the ECS agent. You can modify this file, located at `/etc/ecs/ecs.config`, and name a different cluster. Then restart the ECS agent. This will effectively "move" the EC2 instance to the other cluster.

More information about `ecs.config` in the documentation - http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/ecs-agent-config.html

After the modification, it is possible to verify by sending an HTTP request to the ECS Agent metadata service and see the new cluster displayed. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/ecs-agent-update.html

The ECS cluster itself also needs to be notified. Can use the Register/Deregister API calls for this, for example using the AWS CLI:

- http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ecs/register-container-instance.html
- http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ecs/deregister-container-instance.html

More housekeeping might be required on the ECS agent itself. Like removing cached checkpoint files, etc. https://github.com/aws/amazon-ecs-agent/issues/139#issuecomment-123061463

Comment: i modified `/etc/ecs/ecs.config` to `ECS_CLUSTER=devcluster` and restarted ec2 instance. but the instance still appear on `qacluster`

Comment: @sith I updated the answer with details about registration of instances in the ECS Cluster metadata. Might need to be updated as well, or else the cluster does not know about a new instance or about a removed one.

Answer (score 0):

Updated for ECS optimized AMI image as of May 2021. The sudo start command is not present and the checkpoint file /var/lib/ecs/data/ecs_agent_data.json changed to agent.db.

1. Edit `/etc/ecs/ecs.config` as previously described (add ECS_CLUSTER=devcluster).
2. Rename the agent state file with `mv /var/lib/ecs/data/agent.db /var/lib/ecs/data/agent.db.old`
3. Restart the ECS agent using `sudo systemctl restart ecs`

Check the status of the agent with `systemctl status ecs`, you want it to display *Active: active (running)*.

This was a bit frustrating to figure out because the Amazon online documentation I found still displays the old information. Couldn't have done it without devops!